# How to add a custom class to an element in a WordPress post using WP hooks via Snippets?

Tags: wordpress, code-snippets, add-filter

I'm trying to add a single class (`my-class`) to an element in a WordPress post (LearnDash Theme). I fount out that it can be done using a hook via `add_filter`, but no how I could figure it out.

The sample code that I found looks like this:

```
add_filter( 'body_class', 'custom_body_class' );
/**
 * Add custom field body class(es) to the body classes.
 *
 * It accepts values from a per-page custom field, and only outputs when viewing a singular static Page.
 *
 * @param array $classes Existing body classes.
 * @return array Amended body classes.
 */
function custom_body_class( array $classes ) {
    $new_class = is_page() ? get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'body_class', true ) : null;

    if ( $new_class ) {
        $classes[] = $new_class;
    }

    return $classes;
}
```

In this sample code the class is added to pages only but I need to add it to "posts". I tried `is_post()` but it didn't work out. I even tried it on a page, but didn't work also.

In my case I want to add a class to an element with ID `learndash-page-content`.

Existing code:

```
<div id="learndash-page-content">...</div>
```

What I'm struggling to do:

```
<div id="learndash-page-content" class="my-class">...</div>
```

What do I need to do to get it working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that is indeed the syntax of the element, you might want to try string manipulation on the output (which you will capture like this:)

```
function start_modify_html() {
   ob_start();
}

function end_modify_html() {
   $html = ob_get_clean();
   $html = str_replace( '<div id="learndash-page-content">', '<div id="learndash-page-content" class="my-class">', $html );
   echo $html;
}

add_action( 'wp_head', 'start_modify_html' );
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'end_modify_html' );
```

Comment: It works like a charm! I really appreciate it! Thanks a million!!!